# CMD prompt list all files and subfiles within specific date range

Tags: cmd, windows-7-x64

I have to do an audit on all the files on a specific drive(N:) that were created in 2015. Basically I have to verify that a percentage of these files for each date created were put in the right place, check for quality, etc. I have messed around with the command prompt and I can get a list of all files with:

dir N: /S /A:-d

I have spent hours on google doing searches and a lot point to using the find command, but every time I use the find command I get an error stating the parameters are incorrect. Can anyone give me the correct command to do this.

I have changed my command to:

forfiles /p N: /s /c "cmd /c echo @path @fdate" /d +01/01/2015

which gives me the files on the N drive but no subfiles. How do I get this including all subfiles?

Comment: Have a look at the `forfiles` command. Use `forfiles /?` to get a description. If the problem is with `find`, then please post the command you are using in the question.

Comment: Okay, so I tried "forfiles /P N: /s /d +01/01/2015" and this just gave me a list of the folders.

Comment: I saw a command in the forfiles /? that said I could use dir /s but when I tried to edit my command to "forfiles /P N: DIR /s /d +01/01/2015" it gave me an error of invalid arguments/option - 'dir'

Comment: The /S switch is "like" using /S on the `DIR` command. You cannot use `DIR` on the `forfiles` command. Are you saying that no file names appeared in the output of `forfiles`, only directories?

Comment: correct only folder names show, no path, no date, no file names

Comment: That is not the result I get. What is the exact `forfiles` command you are using. And, I have to ask, are there files that exist? Please try `/M *.txt` or some other known mask that you know exists.

Comment: so far I have gotten a command "forfiles /p N: /s /c "cmd /c echo @path @fdate" /d +01/01/2015" which is giving me the path and the date but it is only showing folders and not files. I need all files(not folder names) on the (N:) drive that are also in subfolders. And yes, there are numerous files in these folders.

Comment: I think I was unclear on my explanation, it is showing files directly on the (N:) drive but nothing within the subfolders of that drive.

Comment: When I use `forfiles /P N: /s /M "*.zip" /C "cmd /c echo @relpath"`, I am getting file names. Please try the /M switch.

Comment: There are multiple file types I am searching for .png .tiff .pdf how would I specify multiple?

Comment: I tried [FORFILES /P N: /M "*.*" /S /C "CMD /C ECHO @PATH @FDATE" /D +01/01/2015] which looked like it started to work but then it got stuck after the 3rd file and didn't go back to the main prompt or anything

Comment: What OS are you running? XP, 7, 8.1, 10?

Comment: I am using windows 7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107554/discussion-between-liturgist-and-donovan-kight).